# Laravel 5 Resolving dependencies in ServiceProvider

Tags: php, dependencies, laravel-5, ioc-container, service-provider

I have a class which acts like a storage (add/get item). I try to bind it as a singleton in one service provider, and resolve it in another's boot method.

The code is changed for simplicity.

**app/Providers/BindingProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class MyBindingFacade extends Facade {
    public static function getFacadeAccessor() {
        return 'my.binding';
    }
}

class MyBinding {

    protected $items = [];

    public function add($name, $item) {
        $this->items[$name] = $item;
    }
    public function get($name) {
        return $this->items[$name];
    }
    public function getAll() {
        return $this->items;
    }

}

class BindingProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton('my.binding', function($app) {
            return $app->make('App\Providers\MyBinding');
        });
    }

    public function provides() {
        return [
            'my.binding',
        ];
    }
}
```

**app/Providers/ResolvingProvider.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Providers\MyBinding;

class ResolvingProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot(MyBinding $binding) {
        $binding->add('foo', 'bar');

        // $manual = $this->app->make('my.binding');
        // $manual->add('foo', 'bar');
    }

    public function register() {}

}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/WelcomeController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Providers\MyBindingFacade;

class WelcomeController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        dd(MyBindingFacade::getAll()); // debug items
    }
}
```

When I try to debug MyBinding state in my `WelcomeController` I'm getting empty item array. However, if I uncomment `$manual` part from my ResolvingProvider it returns an array containing 'foo' => 'bar'. Does it mean IoC resolution is broken in `ServiceProvider::boot()` method or am I misusing Laravel functionality?

Laravel version: 5.0.28

**UPDATE:** Added code sample from WelcomeController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
$this->app->singleton('my.binding', function($app) {
    return $app->make('App\Providers\MyBinding');
});
```

You're saying: *`my.binding` is a singleton* and resolves to an instance of `App\Providers\MyBinding`.

That doesn't mean that `App\Providers\MyBinding` is registered as singleton too. What you should do instead is this:

```
$this->app->singleton('App\Providers\MyBinding');

$this->app->bind('my.binding', function($app) {
    return $app->make('App\Providers\MyBinding');
});
```

Because the Facade binding uses `$app->make()` you should get the same instance you registered with `$this->app->singleton()` right above.

Comment: Seems like I was asking IoC for some kind of black magic. Now I get it. Thank you, Lukas!

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are not using the Facade, you should be using:

```
use App\Providers\MyBindingFacade as MyBinding;
```

Which will in fact call make it using 'my.binding'.

Comment: Shouldn't `MyBindingFacade` always return me an instance behind `my.binding`? Could you provide more information about your solution?

Comment: I've also updated my question with code sample from my `WelcomeController` where `MyBindingFacade` is used.